# Laptop mSata SSD data loss after shutdown

Tags: ssd, shutdown, filesystem-corruption, msata

Laptop: Acer Aspire M5-481TG
mSata SSD: Liteonit LMT-128-M3M
SSD is first in boot order, I have also tried every other boot order but nothing works.
I have also tried resetting BIOS settings.
Issue:

If I install Windows 8.1, everything goes perfectly and Im able to boot into windows after installation. At first boot, all updates install correctlý. Chdsk, crystaldiskmark/info and every other possible hard drive health check program shows that the harddrive is in perfect condition and functioning at full speed.

Rebooting works, if I reboot the computer it always goes to windows. BUT, BUT if I shut the computer down and try starting again, it never boots back to windows, never. "No bootable device -- insert boot disk and press any key"

I can never boot back to windows if I shut the computer down. I can only restart after installing Windows 8.1 64bit, so restarting works and windows loads after installation. After shut down, I can never get back to Windows.

Also, if I insert the USB/DVD of Windows 8.1 in and go into the setup, it says that the hardrive is 120 gigs of UNALLOCATED space, it doesnt show any partitions or anything else and system recovery, system repair and nothing else works. Its like everything simply disappears, all the content from the drive disappears.

Also, I think this is worth noting as well: I had windows 7 installed before, and after shutting it down one day it wouldnt boot back up, so I had to rescue the drive with test disk in linux, for some reason the drive had gone to raw data I guess and I had to do all kinds of things with test disk to be able to recover all the files and I did so successfully.

TLDR: I install windows 8.1, can boot into it and install updates, restart as many times as I want. BUT, if I shut the computer down, I can never boot back to windows. It says "No bootable device". Have tried every possible boot order and whatnot. No option to change UEFI/LEGACY in Bios either. Have tried both, AHCI and IDE.

Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: Did you try disabling write caching?

Answer (score 0):

Do you run the latest firmware on your SSD? seems like there is an update available which is supposed to provide "Enhanced compatibility with Windows 8", available e.g. from Dell:

http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/Drivers/DriversDetails?driverId=VTNJT